# Auto reassign owner when create table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, sql-grant

I have Postgres Database with schema `sandbox` where the role `bi_developer` has all grants.

Real users have personal roles, where `bi_developer` is a parent.

But when some users create a new table, other users haven't permission for it. And I make `GRANT ALL ....` for `bi_developer` every now and again.

Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Postgres or Greenplum? They are quite different

Comment: See if this [Default Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) works for you.

Answer (score 0):

We try different viriants, included default priveleges, but nothing work as expected in our Greenplum installation, now we use trigger, wich transfer all new tables into `read_only` role:

```
-- CREATE FUNCTION
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sandbox.set_object_owner()
  RETURNS event_trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
  DECLARE
    obj record;
BEGIN
  FOR obj IN SELECT schemaname, objname, subtype 
    from pg_stat_operations 
        where schemaname = 'sandbox' 
    and actionname = 'CREATE'
    and subtype in ('TABLE', 'VIEW') 
  loop
    if obj.subtype = 'TABLE'
    then
      EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s.%s OWNER TO read_only', obj.schemaname, obj.objname);
    end if;
    if obj.subtype = 'VIEW'
    then 
      EXECUTE format('ALTER VIEW %s.%s OWNER TO read_only', obj.schemaname, obj.objname);
    end if;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$

-- CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER trg_set_owner
  ON ddl_command_end
  WHEN tag IN ('CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE AS', 'CREATE VIEW')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sandbox.set_object_owner();
```